# Why is {fmt} slower than std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, performance, stringstream, fmt

From what I read online the {fmt} library is supposed to be incredibly much faster than e.g. stringstreams.

However, I did some simple benchmarking (measuring system time, see code below) and it seems that {fmt} is always slower than e.g. stringstreams. Am I getting something wrong?

```
uint64_t start;
uint64_t stop;

long MAXCOUNT = 10000000;

std::srand(123);

int* numbers =  new int[MAXCOUNT];
for ( int i = 0; i < MAXCOUNT; i++) {
    numbers[i] = std::rand();
}

{
    std::string result;
    start = currentTimeInMillis();
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAXCOUNT; i++) {
        result += fmt::format("Number {} is great!", numbers[i]);
    }
    stop = currentTimeInMillis();
    fmt::print("timing fmt : {} ms   /   string length: {}\n", stop-start, result.size());
}


{
    std::string result;
    std::stringstream ss;
    start = currentTimeInMillis();
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAXCOUNT; i++) {
        ss << "Number " << numbers[i] << " is great!";
    }
    result = ss.str();
    stop = currentTimeInMillis();
    fmt::print("timing stds: {} ms   /   string length: {}\n", stop-start, result.size());
}
```

A typical result (optimization level O3 - less is even worse) of this code is:

```
timing fmt : 1414 ms   /   string length: 264823200
timing stds: 1287 ms   /   string length: 264823200
```

Comment: Note that you're not only benchmarking the formatting, but also the whole string concatenation. String concatenation like that will include a lot of reallocations which might overshadow the time for the `format` call.

Comment: You could change the line to `fmt::format("{}Number {} is great!", result, numbers[i]));` to avoid the string concatenation

Comment: You are also constructing a new fmt::format each time, but are only constructing the std::stringstream once.  You should construct a std::stringstream inside the for loop, and then `result += ss.str();` inside the loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : That is absolutely right. I should add that eventually I am not interested in benchmarking the formatting itself but in finding the most efficient way of add up formatted strings. However, the formatting itself seemed to be the most time-consuming part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, I don't get the same numbers on my machine, for me `fmt` is faster:

```
timing fmt : 1713 ms   /   string length: 264825935
timing stds: 2483 ms   /   string length: 264825935
```

Second, to get a fair comparison, replace

```
result += fmt::format("Number {} is great!", numbers[i]);
```

with

```
fmt::format_to(std::back_inserter(result), "Number {} is great!", numbers[i]);
```

This improves the timing to (on my machine again)

```
timing fmt : 1153 ms   /   string length: 264825935
timing stds: 2482 ms   /   string length: 264825935
```